# Disable access to local computers in Kali

Tags: kali-linux

How do I disable access to my local devices in Kali Linux? In Windows it's called "Network Browser", and it's empty as long as I have "Network Discovery" feature disabled. But in Kali Linux I can see all my local devices even when I disable network discovery on the respective Windows computer. It doesn't open but it's visible along with its name. And I don't want it to even be visible.

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about setting up firewall rules to drop network traffic to those PCs?

Comment: One of those "PCs" is my router. I think you understand what happens if I disable network traffic to it, lol. And I need to have a connection with my PC on Kali as well. I just don't want them to be "discovered".